# How does aligning structures help in C?

Tags: c, structure

I came across this C code and I'm trying to understand it:

```
typedef long    Mtx_t[4][4];

typedef union {
    Mtx_t m;
    long long int   force_structure_alignment;
} Mtx;
```

The first typedef defines Mtx_t as a 4x4 matrix, that much I understand. But the second typedef for Mtx just calls for the previous type and adds a long long int called force_structure_alignment.

What is the purpose of this? Why not just define Mtx as the 4x4 matrix and be done with it?

Comment: A curious example; since it's a union the size is it's largest type; which on my system would be 128 bytes for `long[4][4]`. Where as the other field is only `8` bytes on my system. It doesn't seem to contribute at all to any alignment. You'd imagine that `force_structure_alignment` would be larger than the other types for the case of it being used for alignment.

Comment: They're forcing it to be aligned on a valid `long long` boundary.  For instance, this could be 8 bytes while `long` might be 4 bytes.  It's not clear why this is desired.  It may be an attempt to improve memory reference performance.  It's also possible they may want to attempt to alias the `Mtx_t` variable with a `long long` to perform larger memory accesses.

Comment: @jacob: The `long[4][4]` only has the alignment requirements of a `long`, so the `long long`'s alignment is probably stricter.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah; I would have thought it would be related to the size of the union. Good catch.

Comment: If structure is aligned you only need to increment by the size of a page or what ever block size it is aligned with (ie `i+32` bytes) when not aligned more math operations has to be done to get the size to increment. Also if memory is partitioned into 64 bit sections for each address, incrementing a structure whose size is aligned to 64 bits means just incrementing the address like *struct +1 instead of having logical components lay across intermediate physical address boundaries. It really depends on the implementation. In directx 12 matrix objects should be memory aligned.

Answer (score 4):

As the name implies, they're trying to force `Mtx`es to be placed in memory with the address alignment requirements of a `long long`, rather than a `long`. This may be important for requirements imposed by the OS or the processor architecture. Google suggests that "Mtx" is probably short for "mutex", and a C mutex implementation would be dealing with some pretty low-level interfaces.

Comment: A reasonable requirement for atomic values is to keep a separate generation counter (to avoid ABA) and use double-word compare-and-swaps. So even if you require only two adjacent but separate longs, the machine may require them to be aligned on double the size for the atomic operation.

Comment: I think that Mtx is definitely Matrix, beacause [4][4] forms a matrix shape, and in Mtx_t, the 't' can stand for 'transformation' as in a transofrmation matrix.

Comment: @user3360203: The [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=mtx_t) for "mtx_t" are all about mutexes, but [refining the search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mtx_t+force_structure_alignment) suggests that you're probably right about it meaning "matrix". It also suggests that maybe we're not supposed to have access to this code; it seems to be proprietary code from the Nintendo 64.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done for efficiency with the processor architecture. For example, if the size of Mtx_t is an odd number of bytes and the hardware's instruction set/memory architecture imposes a cost when accessing an odd address, you'll want to make sure all your Mtx_t records will sit along addresses which are cheaper to access.

There also might be some need to work with a fixed size block of memory such as with coprocessors. Using a padded structure can make that easier to manage.

Read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Answer (score 1):

There is data bus on the chip which carries data for read/write. For faster memory access, these buses designed to carry data in multiple of bytes e.g. 4/8/16 bytes. But these bus can't read/write data from any arbitrary address with equal efficiency. For example an 8-byte data bus will be faster to read/write data from a memory which is aligned at 8-byte boundary. That's why for high efficiency, large size data/structure are recommended to be aligned such that a fast access be feasible. In your example it is done by exploiting compiler's implementation of managing structures which may not yield the desire result. But compiler can be explicitly told about the alignment of a variable by using keywords e.g. gcc uses 'aligned' keyword